# Create a DeltaXML Core instance using a different version of Saxon

Tags: java, xslt, saxon, deltaxml

I'm using DeltaXML Core v7.1 and its Java API (PipelinedComparatorS9 class) to implement an XML comparison tool.

My code first uses our own Saxon XSLT processor (v9.6.0.9) to pre-process the XML for the comparison. The Saxon processor uses our company's OEM license, activated in code rather than via an external license file, so how can we use this same processor instead of DeltaXML's built-in processor?

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues in your question:

1) **the version of the Saxon processor you want to use with DeltaXML Core**

The DeltaXML Core v7.1 API supports Saxon 9.3 through to Saxon 9.5 (Saxon 9.5.1.5 is actually included with the distribution). If a version of Saxon outside this range is found, an 'Unsupported Saxon version' exception is thrown. The intention for the next release of Core (nominally 8.2) is to support Saxon 9.5 through to Saxon 9.7, though this is still subject to change. Unfortunately, this means that, until the next release of Core, you will need to ensure that your XSLT is compatible with Saxon 9.5. Such XSLT changes are most likely to be related to changes in the XSLT 3.0 specification (currently a Candidate Recommendation).

2) **how to use an OEM licensed version of Saxon with DeltaXML Core**

The DeltaXML PipelinedComparatorS9 and DocumentComparator classes both have constructor overloads that take a Saxon Processor instance as an argument. A Processor instance passed in as an argument here will be used internally also - instead of the processor included in the distribution. The simplified Java code below shows this approach for PipelinedComparatorS9:

```
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmNode;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor;
import com.deltaxml.cores9api.PipelinedComparatorS9;

Processor saxonProcessor= new Processor(true);
// invoke your own activation here:
Activator.activate(saxonProcessor);
XdmNode input1= loadInput1(saxonProcessor);
XdmNode input2= loadInput2(saxonProcessor);

PipelinedComparatorS9 pcS9= new PipelinedComparatorS9(saxonProcessor);
XdmNode resultNode= pcS9.compare(input1, input2);
```